# Strange Error XML parsing: line 1, character 2038, illegal xml character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query,

```
DECLARE @Result XML;
SELECT @Result = (  SELECT  PD.* 
                FROM    [ProductDetailedDescriptions] PD
                        LEFT JOIN [Products] P ON (PD.ProductID= P.ID)
                WHERE   PD.ProductID = 23
                        AND P.RetailerID = 1
                        AND PD.LanguageID = 1
                ORDER BY [ORDER]
                FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('root')
            )
```

This throws `XML parsing: line 1, character 2038, illegal xml character`. When I select just,

```
SELECT  PD.* 
FROM    [ProductDetailedDescriptions] PD
        LEFT JOIN [Products] P ON (PD.ProductID= P.ID)
WHERE   PD.ProductID = 23
        AND P.RetailerID = 1
        AND PD.LanguageID = 1
ORDER BY [ORDER]
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('root')
```

It shows the following xml,

```
<root>
   ..............................................
   ..............................................
  <PD>
    <ID>4187</ID>
    <ProductID>23</ProductID>
    <Header>aa</Header>
    <Description>with &#x3;other</Description>
    <Order>7</Order>
    <LanguageID>1</LanguageID>
  </PD>
```

Note the **#x3**. In my app it's just a space. Is it a bug n SQL Server?

Comment: What is the content of the respective Description column if you query it directly without the CML conversion and what is the collation and datatype of this column?

Comment: @TToni, Nvarchar(MAX). The collation is Default. I is an unvisible char. See the image above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&#x03;` is an invalid character in XML.

From [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets)

> Char     ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] |
>   [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

Your query that works can be simplified to this:

```sql
select cast(0x3 as char(1)) col
for xml raw
```

The output of the above query is a table with one row and one column with the datatype `nvarchar(max)`.

When assigning to a XML variable you get an error.

```sql
declare @XML xml = 
(
  select cast(0x3 as char(1)) col
  for xml raw
)
```

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 16,
>   illegal xml character

Or when you specify the `type` directive the column will be a XML column and you get a more verbose error.

```sql
select cast(0x3 as char(1)) col
for xml raw, type
```

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 FOR XML could not serialize the
>   data for node 'col' because it contains a character (0x0003) which is
>   not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to
>   binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64
>   directive.

You have to remove the illegal characters before you generate the XML.

```sql
declare @XML xml =
replace((
       select cast(0x3 as char(1)) col
       for xml raw
       ), '&#x03;', '')
```

Comment: But why sql server throwing error during assigning. is it make sense?

Comment: @user960567 The error makes sense. That you do not get an error when not assigning or using `type` is somewhat confusing. But it is returning a nvarchar so it works but it is strange to me.